# Template alias for type trait doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm practicing SFINAE by a simple custom type trait:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A{ int i, j; };

// Type trait
template<typename T>
struct is_class_A{ static const bool value = false; };

template<>
struct is_class_A<A>{ static const bool value = true; };

// (1)
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_class_A<T>::value> foo(const T& t){
    puts("Hi!\n");
}


int main() {
    A a;
    foo(a);   // allowed
    //foo(1); // not allowed
}
```

works as expected. However, using a template alias

```cpp
template <typename T>
using is_class_A_v = is_class_A<T>::value;


// (1)
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_class_A_v<T>> foo(const T& t){
    puts("Hi!\n");
}
```

yields the compiler error:

```
<source>:37:22: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'is_class_A<T>::value'
using is_class_A_v = is_class_A<T>::value;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     typename 
<source>:40:18: error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
std::enable_if_t<is_class_A_v<T>> foo(const T& t){
```

On the other hand, by using

```cpp
template <typename T>
using is_class_A_v = typename is_class_A<T>::value;
```

I obtain the error message

```
error: template argument for non-type template parameter must be an expression
std::enable_if_t<is_class_A_v<T>> foo(const T& t){
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Wrong syntax for template variable. Do you mean `template <typename T>
const bool is_class_A_v = is_class_A<T>::value;`?

Comment: `value` is a value, not a type.  To make an alias for it, you need to create a variable template.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @Jarod42 could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Unrequested Off Topic Suggestion: don't reinvent the wheel: when possible, use what standard library make available. So use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` and inheritance defining `is_class_A`: `template <typename> struct is_class_A : public std::false_type { }; template <> struct is_class_A<A> : public std::true_type { };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template variable syntax would be:

```
template <typename T> const bool is_class_A_v = is_class_A<T>::value;
```